# Reading files in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have an Erlang app that fetches some key/value pair from files.
In one of the files, instead of the key/value pairs, I have a path to a different folder, in which it has the key/value pairs.

The reading of the files are working fine, but whenever I have to read the path from a file and just then read the subsequent file, the app is complaining that the file is nonexistent.

If I jump into the container and check, I can see the file and the subsequent file. So I guess I'm missing something.

Here is what I have:

```
get_kvs("keyvalue.properties"), %% <-- This works

{ok, PathToFile} = file:read_file("pathtofile.properties"),
get_kvs(PathToFile), %% <-- This crashes
```

Files:

- `keyvalue.properties`:

```
key_1=val_1
key_2=val_2
key_3=val_3
```

- `pathtofile.properties`:

```
/data/myfolder/hidden_keyvalue.properties
```

- `/data/myfolder/hidden_keyvalue.properties`:

```
extra_key1=extra_val1
extra_key2=extra_val2
extra_key3=extra_val3
```

And the `get_metadata` function:

```
get_metadata(FileName) ->
    io:format(FileName),
    {ok, MetadataFile} = file:read_file(FileName),
    io:format(MetadataFile),
    Lines = binary:split(MetadataFile, <<"\n">>, [trim, global]),
    make_tuples(Lines, []).

make_tuples([Line|Lines], Acc) ->
    [Key, Value] = binary:split(Line, <<"=">>),
    make_tuples(Lines, [{Key, Value}|Acc]);
make_tuples([], Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc).
```

Whenever running it I can see that the `PathToFile` is being properly populated, but when I try to read the path I get the error below:

```
keyvalue.propertiesextra_key_1=extra_val_1
extra_key_2=extra_val_2
extra_key_3=extra_val_3
/data/myfolder/hidden_keyvalue.properties
=CRASH REPORT==== 23-Mar-2022::07:46:30.612093 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: cowboy_stream_h:request_process/3
    pid: <0.735.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,enoent}
      in function  hello_handler:get_metadata/1 (/data/apps/hello_server/src/hello_handler.erl, line 40)
      in call from hello_handler:child_call/1 (/data/apps/hello_server/src/hello_handler.erl, line 28)
```

Any ideas of what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks... Good that I made some assumptions which were not correct. Why don't you remove that `catch` and try? That should help getting to the actual reason of failure. If you can? (Added here so that I can delete the answer later).

Comment: As if I am trying locally, it works...`kvs:get_kvs(PathToFile).
kvs:get_kvs(PathToFile).
extra_key1=extra_val1
extra_key2=extra_val2
extra_key3=extra_val3[{<<"extra_key1">>,<<"extra_val1">>},
 {<<"extra_key2">>,<<"extra_val2">>},
 {<<"extra_key3">>,<<"extra_val3">>}]`

Comment: Are you using `{ok, PathToFile} = file:read_file("pathtofile.properties")`?
I wonder if I need to convert this to a string or something.
Removing the `try/catch` The error is raised in the `get_metadata` function in this line:
`{ok, MetadataFile} = file:read_file(FileName),`.

Comment: It must be having some more info... if failure is from `file:read_file(...)`...

Comment: `{ok, PathToFile} = file:read_file("pathtofile.properties").
{ok,<<"hidden_keyvalue.properties">>}`

Comment: Updated the exception in the question without the try/catch.

Comment: `{error,enoent}` means the file doesn't exist.

Comment: what is this? `/data/extrametadata.properties`?

Comment: same as `keyvalue.properties`, just forgot to clean it. As I've mentioned, I have a couple of files with K/V. For simplicity I added to the initial post just one.

Comment: I've just tested and the file exists, I suspect the issue is in the way I'm calling the function. Because manually through `cat` it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243219/discussion-between-nalin-ranjan-and-juliano-costa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the OP has been modified to reflect the actual point of failure by removing `try-catch`, the error seems to be `{error, enoent }`which means `The file does not exist`. However, the same function is working in some scenarios and not when the path of the file to be read is itself taken from another file.

Just make sure there are mo additional characters, like newlines or non-printable characters after the content of the file which should actually be a valid path.

For example, when I tried with a value as such, `<<"hidden_keyvalue.properties\n\n">>`, then `read_file` gave me same result as `{error, enoent}`.

So it could be possible that the content of the file from which paths are read has additional non-printable characters at the end.

---

### ***Ignore*** (Wrong Assumption)

I tried with a local setup and I think this line inside `make_tuples` is causing that behavior.

```erlang
[Key, Value] = binary:split(Line, <<"=">>) %% <--- This match will succeed only if there are exactly 2 elements in the list produced by binary:split(...).
```

Given we are doing inside `get_metadata`

```erlang
Lines = binary:split(MetadataFile, <<"\n">>, [trim, global]), %% <-- This splits the contents of the keyvalue.properties file into a List
make_tuples(Lines, [])
```

From the provided text, it appears that the content of `keyvalue.proiperties` file is ...

```
key_1=val_1
key_2=val_2
key_3=val_3
/data/myfolder/hidden_keyvalue.properties %% <-- This isn't a valid key-value pair
```

And with that last line, `make_tuples` while doing a match will fail the following way...

```erlang
[Key, Value] = binary:split(<<"/data/myfolder/hidden_keyvalue.properties">>, <<"=">>).
** exception error: no match of right hand side value [<<"/data/myfolder/hidden_keyvalue.properties">>]
```

That pattern-match expression requires exactly 2 elements on the right-hand side(the Term/Value side). Since the line with path-entry in the `keyvalue.properties` does not have an `=`, so the split produces a list with 1 element, and so the match fails.

To address this...

1. We can change the format of `keyvalue.properties` so that every line is a valid `key-value` pair, but not sure how feasible it will be in the context of the program.
2. Or, we can change that pattern-match form of list so that it can accept non-exact number of terms while matching

```erlang
make_tuples([Line|Lines], Acc) ->
    %% [Key|Value] is at least 1 element list, [Key, Value] is exactly 2 elements list
    [Key|Value] = binary:split(Line, <<"=">>), %% <-- Now Value becomes a list of binary
    make_tuples(Lines, [{Key, get_value(Value)}|Acc]); %% <-- Additional get_value function to extract 'Value binary' from the head of the 'Value List' produced in the previous line
make_tuples([], Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc).

get_value([]) ->
    <<>>;
get_value([V|_]) -> V.
```

---

### ***Assumptions***

> `get_kvs` invokes `get_metadata` which in turn invokes `make_tuples`.

> `keyvalue.properties` file content has both valid key-value pairs and also some non-key-value entries

Comment: Hello @Nalin, not really. I've added more context to the question. The file 1 has only K/V, the file 2 has the path for the file 3, and the file 3 has only K/V. The first time I call `get_kvs` it works fine, but when I first fetch the file path from another file, and call the `get_kvs` again, just then, I'm getting the error. I show the 2 calls in the first code block.

Comment: Thanks... Good that I made some assumptions which were not correct. Why don't you remove that `catch` and try? That should help getting to the actual reason of failure. If you can?